# Need advice to improve current RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

Currently I am running a m3.medium SQL Server RDS(20GB storage without IOPS). CPU utilization is under 50% for most of the time(~90%). However, during peak hours(~10%) CPU utilization will hit 100% and my website become extremely slow.

DB instance details(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html)

```
Instance Type   : db.m3.medium
vCPU    : 1
ECU : 3
Memory (GiB)    : 3.75
PIOPS-Optimized : -
Network Performance : Moderate
```

Attached with the overall metrics of my RDS
[image]

How can i reduce the chances of my RDS hitting 100% CPU utilization? Does enable IOPS will helps? Or should i upgrade it into a better instance?

Comment: Looks like a little increase in reads and a much more significant increase in writes is perhaps more or less happening at about the time of your CPU increase.  Turn up a server side trace at about that time and see what's going on; perhaps you can tune queries.  Also, check to see what kind of maintenance may be happening at that time - patches, upgrades, antivirus or other scans, index maintenance(!), etc.

Comment: Is this instance backing something like a web app? There's really nothing going on during the peaks except more connections... so reduce the cost/connection by tuning the queries or introduce caching, or I suppose throw hardware at the problem.